# Ideas on ways to implement simple offsite clone of web app (php / codeigniter / mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database

Have a web app installed on a local internal hardware. I am trying to figure out how best (even if possible) to replicate the data to an external server with the same app installed so they can sync the data between them. So if external they can access via web if internal they can access locally.

PHP / CodeIgniter App running on MySQL.

Had idea of having the local app remotely connect and use the external server DB as the main source but then thought what if internet isn't available how best could I handle that?

Answer (score 0):

So your webservice runs on a machine in your local network. And if you're not on the local network you want to connect via Internet?

Can you detect when you're on the local network? Maybe this is as simple as trying `http://mywebservice/`, otherwise switch to Internet mode `http://mywebservice.mydomain.com`.

---

You could also consider dropping local availability. Does it happen a lot that you are on the local network but don't have Internet access?

Comment: Otherway around. Basically the data locally and remote needs to be the same in realtime. But if internet (remote) is not available  then it will then carry on working until remote is available and then upload / diff the data to the remote so they are back in sync and also grab any data from the remote that happened when connection not available.

Comment: Oh, you mean an _offline_ mode? That's something completely different. Don't run PHP locally .. that's weird.

Comment: Not locally its on a local webserver. in house.

Comment: Ok, so back to the original idea. Don't run two servers. Run one that is available locally and externally.